# extract several values from json using json query ansible

Tags: json, parsing, ansible, json-query

I m having a file like:

```
{
        "account": "/system1/test", 
        "description": "", 
        "desired_state": "active", 
        "id": "f957e20c-0033-4523-9020-e31304401149",
        "status": "active", 
        "tags": [], 
        "time_audited": "2018-01-14T23:12:22Z", 
        "time_created": "2018-01-14T22:34:53Z", 
        "time_updated": null
}
```

When I try to get a value out as:

```
with_items: "{{orch_details.content|from_json|json_query('status')}}"
```

Everything is fine.

I want to extract several other values but I can't combine them to the `json_query` like:

```
with_items: "{{orch_details.content|from_json|json_query('status, account, description')}}"
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: How about checking [the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) before posting on SO?

Answer (score 3):

I think the comment is trying to point out that `json_query` uses JMESPath for the filters. You can read up a bit on it at http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html.

In your examples, you could do something like the following to get an array of the values:

```
with_items: "{{orch_details.content|from_json|json_query('[status, account, description]')}}"
```

Which would return:

```
[
  "active",
  "/system1/test",
  ""
]
```

Or if you want a new hash maybe:

```
with_items: "{{orch_details.content|from_json|json_query('{"status": status, "account": account, "desc": description]')}}"
```

Which would return:

```
{
  "status": "active",
  "account": "/system1/test",
  "desc": ""
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy , your solution works fine, i m a newbie :( , the docs indeed shows something similar

Comment: The comment is trying to point out that questions on SO should show [research effort. A lot. An absurd amount.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2947502)