# Ansible clean up task output

Tags: json, ansible

I have the following playbook, how can I clean up my returned data removing all the extra characters?

```
  tasks:
   - name: Health Status
     shell: curl -XGET 'http://{{ ansible_host }}:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
     retries: 5
     delay: 10
     register: health

   - name: Print Health check
     debug: var=health.stdout_lines[2],health.stdout_lines[4]
```

Current Result

```
ok: [ELK22] => {
    "health.stdout_lines[2],health.stdout_lines[4]": "(u'  \"status\" : \"green\",', u'  \"number_of_nodes\" : 1,')"
}
```

Required Result

```
[ELK22] => {
status: green
number of nodes: 1
}
```

Comment: From your description snippet I understand that you like to know [How to check Elasticsearch cluster health?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34410556/6771046), right? And you like to access/get specific keys from that JSON response only, right?

Comment: Yes, as you can see the current result I get the data I need but I want it sanitised removing the u,\, etc.

Comment: Since you get a JSON response already, you could get the key:values directly from it, I assume. Need to setup a short test since I know the syntax right now not out of my head ...

Comment: Seems like you are getting the string representation of a JSON, and want to convert it to a JSON with the [`from_json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/from_json_filter.html) filter

Comment: @VladimirBotka I have provided the exact code I used along with the exact result. Why are you trying to close this post?

Comment: @VladimirBotka Do you have elasticsearch installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example output of [How to check Elasticsearch cluster health?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34410556/6771046), a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    health:
      stdout: |
        {
          "cluster_name" : "xxxxxxxx",
          "status" : "green",
          "timed_out" : false,
          "number_of_nodes" : 2,
          "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
          "active_primary_shards" : 15,
          "active_shards" : 12,
          "relocating_shards" : 0,
          "initializing_shards" : 0,
          "unassigned_shards" : 0,
          "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
          "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
          "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
        }

  tasks:

  - name: Show value
    debug:
      msg: "{{ health.stdout | from_json | json_query('number_of_nodes') }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show value] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '2'
```

Comment: Fails, get 

FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ health.stdout | from_json | json_query('number_of_nodes') }}): expected string or buffer"}

Comment: new error : {"msg": "Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\n'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}

Comment: Fails with:
**FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\n**

I used:

   - name: test
     debug:
       msg: "{{ health.stdout | from_yaml }}"

   - name: debug
     debug: var=health|type_debug

Comment: I know I've been told to use stout, but shouldn't I be using something that include stout_lines?

Comment: I have got your example working now thanks. I would like to bing back the status as well as I mentioned. But also with the text associated like:

status : green
number of nodes : 1

How can I add this to the jquery?

Comment: To [Extract several values from JSON using json_query in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48256584/6771046) …